# Anyone knows a website, project or repository where i can find add-ons, themes and widgets for Vaadin framework beyond the official website?

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I am beginning to develop some applications using Vaadin framework and would like to know if anyone knows of a website, project or repository where i can find add-ons, themes and widgets for Vaadin framework beyond the official site https://vaadin.com/directory.

As Vaadin uses GWT under the hood (which I also do not know too deeply yet), it would also be interesting to know if i can use components made ​​for GWT in Vaadin without having to adapt or rewrite these components.

Of course, there is always the option of developing custom components, but i want to know the best components that are already out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All existing vaadin add-ons and themes presented in the official directory and there are no other places where you could download them.
You can find some usefull projects on official vaadin github account: 
https://github.com/vaadin